# (Android button) how to implement Two line text with different colors on one button

Tags: android, button

In my android app development, I have one button, the button text is not a single color text, it is two lines text, with each line uses different color for line text. How to implement this? "Two lines" can be simply implemented by adding "\n" in the text, I don know how to set different colors for each line text on the button. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 8):

Try to use Html.fromHtml when setting text to a button:

```
Button button = (Button) getElementById(R.id.some_button);
button.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='red'>First line</font><br/><font color='blue'>Second line</font>"));
```

Comment: Hi, Konstantin, Thank you for your reply, actually I know what you said, But <font> is a deprecated HTML tag, that's why I ask the question here.

Comment: Why does that bother you? You are not required to use cutting edge HTML when it comes to android TextViews. You can also try to style text on the fly using this google guide http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#selectingtext